# How to escape " ' " in sql

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Hi I am searching for a name combination in database. I am passing the combination as follows

```
"firstName='" + firstName + "'", "middleName='" + middleName + "'", "lastName='" + lastName + "'"
```

This works fine. But the problem comes where there are some " ' " in names how can i rectify it? eg: Johns' or Jerry's etc causes exception

Comment: Why don't you try to use `PreparedStatement`? I think it's better

Comment: @TuTran I wish I could upvote your comment many more times. Post an answer!

Comment: Ignore all of the string manipulation answers here, they are all still vulnerable to SQL Injection which is a serious problem these days. I seriously recommend you read [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection).

Comment: @Jaison: Sorry, your original post did not mention about **Hibernate**! So I recommend you using `PreparedStatement`. See my anwser for solution for `Hibernate`

Comment: No its my mistake that I tagged it to sql other than hibernate. Sorry

Answer (score 11):

use preparedStatement it is easy for you

```
ps.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO tb_name values(?,?) WHERE id=?");
ps.setString(1,firstName);
ps.setString(2,middleName);
ps.setInt(3,id);
ps.execute();
```

Answer (score 4):

At least for MySQL, you have to put another `'` before:

```
INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('this isn''t it');
```

Comment: @Johanna It will escape single quotes, but it's still vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Hibernate, you should use like this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Something s where s.firstName = :firstName and s.middleName = :middleName and s.lastName = :lastName");
query.setString("firstName", firstName);
query.setString("middleName", middleName);
query.setString("lastName", lastName);

List<?> list = query.list();
```

Hope this can help you!
You can see more at [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html) and [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Comment: That is the best solution with hibernate (thought it is not an exact answer to the question, may be there are special reasons why he really needs ')

Comment: how to fix this error if it occurs while trying to save an object using hibernate saveOrUpdate(Object) and the single quotes are in a string that is one of teh fields of teh object

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore sinqle quotation characters (') in SQL by escaping them with a backslash `\'`.

Comment: Escaping with backslash does not work for SQL - at least in general.

Comment: @Johanna The [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html) says to use a preceding backslash in general, but also notes the double quote ability.  In other words, both work.

Comment: That's why it wrote 'in general'. For MySQL the backslash works, for Oracle it does not. Oracle only accepts the double quoted `''`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String firstName="X";
    String middleName="Y";
    String lastName="Z";

 "firstName='" + firstName + "',middleName='" + middleName + "',lastName='" + lastName + "'";
```

You can use this to get output as

```
firstName='X',middleName='Y',lastName='Z'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
firstName = firstName.replace("'" , "''");
```

Use PreparedStatement instead , you would be better with that.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the following also works (at least for MySQL):

```
SELECT login FROM usertable WHERE lastname="O'Neil";
```

Comment: Not for Oracle - there it doesn't work => so don't use it in programs.